# Regular expression - Greedy quantifier

Tags: java, regex

I am really struggling with this question:

```
import java.util.regex.*;    
class Regex2 {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(args[0]);    
        Matcher m = p.matcher(args[1]);    
        boolean b = false;    
        while(b = m.find()) {    
            System.out.print(m.start() + m.group());    
        }    
    }
}
```

When the above program is run with the following command:

```
java Regex2 "\d*" ab34ef
```

It outputs `01234456`. I don't really understand this output. Consider the following indexes for each of the characters:

```
a b 3 4 e f
^ ^ ^ ^ ^ ^
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

Shouldn't the output have been `0123445`?

I have been reading around and it looks like the RegEx engine will also read the end of the string but I just don't understand. Would appreciate if someone can provide a step by step guide as to how it is getting that result. i.e. how it is finding each of the numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is helpful to change

```
System.out.print(m.start() + m.group());
```

to

```
System.out.println(m.start() + ": " + m.group());
```

This way the output is much clearer:

```
0: 
1: 
2: 34
4: 
5: 
6:
```

You can see that it matched at 7 different positions: at position 2 it matched string "34" and at any other position it matched an empty string. **Empty string matches at the end** as well, which is why you see "6" at the end of your output.

Note that if you run your program like this:

```
java Regex2 "\d+" ab34ef
```

it will only output

```
2: 34
```

Comment: @fge Nope. Shell does **not** turn "\d+" into "d+". See bash manpage.

Comment: Yes indeed, sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @AdamZalcman, can you elaborate on the **Empty string** at the end. Is there a hidden termination character? Like C's `\0` why is there an empty char at the end of the string? Does the bash shell inject a `\n` or `\r` I am confused as to why there are 6 indices.